# I am trying to log in PCF through .Net Core but logs not showing in PCF

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, pcf

So my log is:

```
public SomeController(IInterface _interface, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        inmessageRepository = _inmessageRepository;
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("InMessageController");

    }
```

Then I have my post API, which does the work. I need logging for this API.

```
[Route("/api/Someapi")]
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult<SomeModel>> SomeMethod([FromBody] SomeModel message)
```

{ //Logic

```
    logger.LogInformation("Somestring", value);
    logger.LogInformation($"Hello");
    logger.LogInformation("Hello");
    logger.LogInformation("Helloo");
    logger.LogInformation("SalesOrderID", msg.SalesOrderId);
```

}

Comment: You need to register it a logger provider in the Program.cs file

Comment: Here I have logged NLog
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                })
                .UseNLog();